# Refresh Ember-Data collection after query change

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Well, not 100% emberish way, but what if I need to filter collection on server using some query with no location change. I have the following solution:

```
Twicl.GroupsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  query: '' //bound to a textfield

  queryChanged: ( ->
    clearTimeout(@delay) 
    @delay = setTimeout ( => @target.send('refresh') ), 500
  ).observes('query')


Twicl.GroupsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  model: ->
    @store.find 'group',
      q: @controllerFor('groups.index').get('query') //Here is no @controller yet, why? :( It's assigned in setup() as I see.

  actions:
    refresh: ->
      @controller.set 'content', @model()
```

Is there more natural way to do so? I see query object on content, but collection doesn't reflect any changes of it. Other ways how it could be done?